# php equivalent to following sha1 encryption c# code

Tags: c#, php, encryption, sha1

I have tried converting the following c# code for sha1 password encryption check to a PHP version, but seem to be failing:

As this code goes in my understanding-> 1) Encode into ASCII 2)Stores in byte array 3) encrypt that byte array into sha1 and stores into again in byte array new byte[60] 4)converts that byte array in 64 bit string. I am not able to get the byte string part in following code.

```
 private static string ComputeHas(byte[] arry){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arry.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(arry);
}
public static string SHA1HashEncode(string pwd)
{
    SHA1 sh = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] arr = new byte[60];
    string hash = "";
    byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pwd);
    arr = sh.ComputeHash(array);
    hash = ComputeHas(arr);
    return hash;
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
//convert string to ascii 
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($pwd, 'ASCII'); $i++) {

$pwd1=ord($pwd[$i]); 
} 

//sha1 encryption of password 
$pwd2=sha1($pwd1);
```

What i have tried so far to get possible exact is following:
//convert string to ascii

```
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($pwd, 'ASCII'); $i++)
{
    $pwd1=ord($pwd[$i]);
    $pwd2[]=$pwd1; 
}

//convert array to string
$pwdString = serialize($pwd2);

//compute hase of string
$pwdHash= array();
$pwdHash[]=array_fill(0,60,sha1($pwdString));

$pwdHashString=serialize($pwdHash);

//convert to 64 bit string encodeing

$pwd64encode=base64_encode($pwdHashString);
print_r($pwd64encode);
```

But i am not getting exact out of C# code in php.

Comment: so, show us what you tried then. We're not a *free* code conversion service.

Comment: which part was giving you trouble?

Comment: @maskofa Don't post code in comments like that, edit your question.

Comment: @maskofa I edited your question. Do not re-edit.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using, the sha1($str) function works with (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5)

Comment: @DimitrisBatsougiannis PHP 5.3

Comment: @user1666620 byte array part in the above code

Answer (score 0):

From PHP's documentation about [SHA1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)

```
$variable = sha1("input");
```

Comment: they want PHP; this isn't PHP. Edit and as per your edit - from your original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32117628/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited, as I didn't understood the question

Comment: I will admit that their "question" was unclear; it's in their title *"php equivalent to followin sha1 encryption c# code"*

Comment: OP added what they tried in comments, I edited their question to contain it.

Comment: @DimitrisBatsougiannis, Thanks for prompt reply.  I am looking for exact equivalent of above code in php.